# List combination in where clause

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

Here is the scenerio, I have a input data and a table `table1`

```
   Input  Data                       Table1
Customer Id   Campaign ID       CustomerId   CampaignID
    1              1                 4            2
    1              2                 6            3
    2              3                 1            1
    1              3                 5            5
    4              2                 9            8                         
    4              4
    5              5
```

I want to query table1 such that it return only those values from the where clause which are not present in table1. So the result will be as below

```
                      Result

            Customer Id   Campaign ID      
                1             2       
                2             3        
                1             3
                4             4
                5             5
```

So the query should be something like

```
select CustomerId, CampaignID from Table1 
where Customer Id in (Input data for customer id) and CampaignId in (Input data for campaign id)
```

. I know this query is not right, but can someone please help.

Is there a way to filter the values given in where clause based on if they are present in table1?

P.S. table1 primary key (CustomerId, CampaignID)

Comment: I want to query table1 such that it return only those values from the where clause which are not present in table1???

Comment: What is input data? Is it a table, a view?

Comment: table1 not present in table 1? You mean table1 not present in input?

Comment: is input data a table ?

Comment: Retagging with CQL, because the SQL-based answer below won't work with Cassandra.

Answer (score -1):

This will work as for your scenario. But it wont show last result record 5,5 since it does not fulfill your need.

```
select * from input where (cust_id, camp_id) not in (select cust_id, camp_id from table1)
```

Comment: This question was improperly tagged with SQL.  Cassandra doesn't support sub-queries or the `NOT` keyword.